# TableSorter Plugin and other Sorting Plugins not Working

Tags: jquery, sorting, coldfusion, html-table, tablesorter

I have been trying to implement sorting into my table, for hours now, using the tablesorter plugin [described here](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/). However, I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm even trying to follow the exact example given but it doesn't work for me.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() 
            { 
                $("myTable").tablesorter(); 
            } 
        ); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <cfoutput>
    <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Due</th>
        <th>Web Site</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td>
        <td>$50.00</td>
        <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bach</td>
        <td>Frank</td>
        <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td>
        <td>$50.00</td>
        <td>http://www.frank.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>Jason</td>
        <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td>
        <td>$100.00</td>
        <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Conway</td>
        <td>Tim</td>
        <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td>
        <td>$50.00</td>
        <td>http://www.timconway.com</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    </cfoutput>
```

I originally downloaded the file and specified an absolute path for the `src`, but that didn't work either. I am trying to use this in a .cfm (ColdFusion) file.

Any input on what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$("myTable").tablesorter();
```

For

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter();
```

The reason being is that you are selecting the element by its Id, which requires the `#` in front of it.

If you want to apply the `tableSorter` plugin to all your tables with the class `tablesorter` then you would do this:

```
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter(); //now you are selecting by class and not by Id
```

[Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/DKdQk/)

Comment: Sorry, but that's not it. I tried it with the pound symbol before to. It accidentally got omitted before I pasted the code.

Comment: @FZ My demo works fine and it's based off of your code. You must have a different issue. If you have Google Chrome, press F12 and relaunch your page. Then click on the "Console" tab and see what errors you see there.

Comment: (Since a burninate edit pushed this thread into the active list ...) FWIW, I ran the exact code from the OP in a .cfm file. Adding the single `#` sign fixed it. Would up vote this, but apparently I already did that the first time around ;-) (FZ - Side note, the `<cfoutput>` tags are unnecessary since there is no cfml code in the page to be evaluated)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved somehow by removing the head tags and rearranging the cfoutput tags:

```
<cfoutput>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() 
            { 
                $("##myTable").tablesorter(); 
            } 
        ); 
</script>

    <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
    <thead> 
    <tr> 
        <th>Last Name</th> 
        <th>First Name</th> 
        <th>Email</th> 
        <th>Due</th> 
        <th>Web Site</th> 
    </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
    <tr> 
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>John</td> 
        <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
        <td>$50.00</td> 
        <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td>Bach</td> 
        <td>Frank</td> 
        <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
        <td>$50.00</td> 
        <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td>Doe</td> 
        <td>Jason</td> 
        <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
        <td>$100.00</td> 
        <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td>Conway</td> 
        <td>Tim</td> 
        <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
        <td>$50.00</td> 
        <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
    </tr> 
    </tbody> 
    </table>  

    </cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I fixed it by adding the css files included in the download.  Note: this is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation.

**It looks like the required css files are style.css and jq.css.**

style.css is located in the download at:

- [root download location]/themes/[blue or green]/style.css
- [root download location]/docs/css/jq.css

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Population 2000 to 2010</title>
<meta  charset="utf-8" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#data-table").tablesorter(); 
    }); 
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jq.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
<h1>Population Change from 2000 to 2010</h1>
<table id="data-table">
  <caption>
  Ranking Tables for States: Population Change from 2000 to 2010
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>2000 population</th>
      <th>2010 population</th>
      <th>Numeric Change</th>
      <th>Percent Change</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>California</td>
      <td>33871648</td>
      <td>37253956</td>
      <td>3382308</td>
      <td>10.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Texas</td>
      <td>20851820</td>
      <td>25145561</td>
      <td>4293741</td>
      <td>20.6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>18976457</td>
      <td>19378102</td>
      <td>401645</td>
      <td>2.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wyoming</td>
      <td>493782</td>
      <td>563626</td>
      <td>69844</td>
      <td>14.1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```